# User Import: How to allow using the same email address for multiple users but different username?

Tags: openid, fusionauth

When trying to batch import users via the fusionauth REST API from our legacy system, the import is rejected since it contains some users making use of the same email address but having different usernames.

I have seen that the Login API of fusionauth supports "loginId" (which can be either the username or the email address). So my question is: does fusionauth allow to use the username to be unique and allow to re-use the email for multiple accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, `username` and `email` are unique within a tenant in FusionAuth because both can be used to authenticate with a password.

If you have multiple users with the same email address but different usernames, that means these are the same actual user, perhaps with different profiles with different usernames.

You'll need to identify how you would like user's to authenticate, using the email address is generally a better option. If this is ok with you, then the username's could be stored in custom data, or on the User Registration.

https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/users#create-a-user
https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/registrations#retrieve-a-user-registration

Comment: How would I support users using both social as well as username-password authentication with the same email? 

If a user uses social-login to create an account, and then uses the same emailID to try and create a username-password account, then fusionauth returns an error with `[duplicate]user.email`. In fact, in this scenario, forgot-password doesn't trigger an email either..probably because this emailID is associated with a social-login account.

Comment: If the user is created during a social login, you may then set the password so that you can also login in directly to FusionAuth using username-password. You can use the Update User API, or the Change Password workflow using email.  Ensure your SMTP configuration is enabled for the forgot passwords to work properly.

Comment: We send+receive emails correctly for email verification and forgot password on regular username-password accounts. Just not the ones that were created with social-login. Ideally, a user will be able to trigger the forgot password workflow from our UI, but that doesn't happen if the user registered an account using social-login and is then trying to run the forgot-password workflow on the same email ID.

Comment: @GuruPrasad this should work, please open a GitHub issue so we can help you resolve it.